# Issue with dice roll simulator

Tags: python

Today I was writing some code for a dice simulator, however I ran into a problem.

This is my code:

```
import random
dice = input("""Hello there!
Welcome to the dice roll simulator.
There are three types of dice which you can roll:
a 4 sided dice, a 6 sided dice and a 12 sided dice.
Please enter either 4,6 or 12 depending on which dice you would like to roll.""")

if dice : 4 or 6 or 12
print ("""You have rolled a """, +dice+ """ sided dice, with the result of : """,(random.randrange(1,dice)))
```

The issue with this is that it is not carrying out the (random.randrange(1,dice)) calculation and instead giving me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Computing science/task 1 code.py", line 9, in <module>
    print ("""You have rolled a """, +roll+ """ sided dice, with the result of : """,(random.randrange(1,dice)))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

I would be very grateful for any possible assistance with my code,

Thank you.

Comment: It's definitely helpful to explain your problem in your title

Comment: The singular of "dice" is "die".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to convert user input (which is `str` type) to number. Secondly, you should expect, that input might be wrong (e.g. letters instead of digits). Finally, it is better to use string substitution (with `.format()` method), than concatenating strings - it is faster, more readable and easier to work with variables of different type.

```
import random
try:
    dice = int(input("...message...:"))
    if dice in (4, 6, 12):
        print ("You have rolled a {}-sided dice, with the result of : {}".format(
            dice, random.randint(1, dice)))
    else:
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    print ("Wrong value for dice.")
```

Comment: @AlexThornton I was just writing explanation. OP either just cp it to his code without any reflection, or start digging in docs to understand and learn something. 
There are just 10 kinds of people, right?

Comment: I ran this code but it didn't work? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try now (parentheses for print were missing and `dice` parameter in format)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with try: is it okay if you explain?

Comment: it catches exception or error (such as if you try to convert string that is not number to integer) and let you react for it. see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError

Comment: I see. About what you said earlier, about giving the user an error message if an integer is not entered when the program asks for a type of dice. I have tried else: print ("""This is not a valid input""") and if dice !=4 and !=6 and !=12 : print ("""This is not a valid input""") , however neither of them seem to work.

Comment: It is always better to check _for valid input_ (the one you expect), and use `else` clause to handle everything else. In my solution, it is done by manually _raising_ `ValueError`, which cause program to jump to `except` clause, just like it would if converting number failed. BTW: you don't need to use triple quotes everywhere, it makes `"` or `'` usually are enough and more readable. And remembet to try also other answers and upvote all those that work for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
print ("""You have rolled a """, +dice+ """ ... """)
                               ^ you have a spurious comma here,
```

which causes the Python interpreter to interpret `+dice` as a unary `+` operator, which doesn't work on strings.

Comment: Exactly. "Unary +" means "a sign in front of something"; in this case the error message says the "something " is a `str`.  So all the information was there in the error message - if you knew how to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import random
dice = input("""Hello there!
Welcome to the dice roll simulator.
There are three types of dice which you can roll:
a 4 sided dice, a 6 sided dice and a 12 sided dice.
Please enter either 4,6 or 12 depending on which dice you would like to roll.""")

if dice in (4 ,6,12) :
    print ("""You have rolled a """, dice, """ sided dice, with the result of : """,(random.randrange(1,dice)))
```